# Passing Array as a BODY in a POST request

Tags: java, json, rest

I am kinda new to Rest assured testing, I have been dealing with diff. json and Api's.
I know how to pass a json object as body for POST request but my code gives error when I try to pass a JSON Array as body for POST request can someone suggest me how to do it.

The code I have been using for json object is

```
 obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path of json"));
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toJSONString();
        Map<String, String> body = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
        response = RestAssuredExtension.PostOpsWithBody(url, body);
```

This code gives class cast exception at
jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; when I pass a json array.

Kindly help me with the same
This is the JSON Array

```
[
    {
    "findingId": "20177044",
    "unsupressAfterDuration": 1669968369043,
    "developer": "manan.girdhar@armorcode.io",
    "kbIds": [],
    "ticketConfigurationId": "3350",
    "customFields": []
  }
]
```

Comment: You've pretty much answered yourself here: `at jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; when I pass a json array`, but I see a confusion from your side - let me clear something up - **`[]` 
 IS a valid JSON** :-) it's not an object, but a valid JSON syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Your parser parses the part of JSON and probably returns a JSONArray, but you are casting it to JSONObject. Maybe you want to use something like

```
obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path of json"));
if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    String jsonString = jsonObject.toJSONString();
    Map<String, String> body = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
    response = RestAssuredExtension.PostOpsWithBody(url, body);
} else {
    throw new Exception("We do not know how to handle non-objects like " + obj.getClass().getName());
    // replace this with list-handling code
}
```

If you want only one code fragment to handle both objects and lists, cast to [JsonStructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonStructure.html).

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question as I found a solution

```
JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray();
        data1.put("findingId", findingIdFinal);
         data1.put("unsupressAfterDuration", "1669968369043");
         data1.put("developer","manan.girdhar@armorcode.io");
         data1.put("kbIds",array1);
         data1.put("ticketConfigurationId", jiraId);
         data1.put("customFields",array1);
        array.put(data1);
        String jsonString = array.toString();
        List<Map<String, String>> body = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, List.class);
        response = RestAssuredExtension.PostOpsWithBodyWithArray(url, body);
```